# How to loop over/test multi-line shell subprocess output in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use *nmap* to determine if a host is online. I want to test for the text `seems down` in the *nmap* output. I've stumbled over several examples which show how to do this but it seems they are for python2 specifically as they generate errors (`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`) when run in python3 (3.9.2). This is my stab below. Is there a way to change this to work with a simple string comparison rather than comparing things in *bytes*?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

ip_addr="10.14.14.22"
p1 = subprocess.Popen (["/usr/bin/nmap", ip_addr, "-p", "U:53,111,137,T:21-25,80,81,82,111,443,139,8080,8006,5666,S:9"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in p1.stdout:
    if b'seems down' in line:
        print ("line: " + str(line))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text=True` option, it is added in python version 3.7.
When you do `text=True`, python communicate with the child process in text mode.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess

ip_addr="10.14.14.22"
p1 = subprocess.Popen (["/usr/bin/nmap", ip_addr, "-p", "U:53,111,137,T:21-25,80,81,82,111,443,139,8080,8006,5666,S:9"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,text=True)

for line in p1.stdout:
    if 'seems down' in line:
        print ("line: " + str(line))
```